# Convert hex file to floats in php

Tags: php, hex

I am reading a BLOB from a SQL data base. The file should contain 1024 float value pairs but I have no clue how to convert them. This is my query:

```
$stmt = $sqlHandle->query('SELECT convert (varchar (max), convert (varbinary (max), blob)) AS dump  FROM data WHERE id = 200
```

This gets me a String with 32842 chars, which starts like this: 
0x000008044072A051E00000004072AD70A00000004072BA8F600000004072C7AE200000004072D4CCC00

I do not know how the blob was created. I only that the first pair should look similar to this after being converted:
248.23112   0.000048741

Can someone explain to me how I get the string converted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <?php
    var_dump(hexdec("0x000008044072A051E00000004072AD70A00000004072BA8F600000004072C7AE200000004072D4CCC00"));
    ?>
```

Comment: This returns a single value: float(4.180510645326E+93). So I guess I need to chop up the string, right? But how? I haven't had the pleasure to work with hex numbers...

Comment: just use imploade() here an example https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_implode

Comment: I do not believe implode is helping here. The string is already kind of imploded. I need to figure out what part of the string is a number. 0x stands for the rest is in hex, right? But then I am lost. Where das the first number start and how many chars belong to it...